# Excel - count days in each month between two dates excluding weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an excel formula which can be dragged across a row of cells to give the number of days in each month between two specified dates. E.g:

```
1  | START DATE | END DATE  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Aug  |...
   ---------------------------------------------------------
2  |  28/06/23  | 04/07/123 |   0   |  3    |  2    |   0   |...
```

I have this so far:

`=MAX(0,MIN(IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(C$1&"-23"),0))-MAX($A2,DATEVALUE(C$1&"-23"))+1)`

Which gives this output:

[image of ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzPs9.png)

Is there any way to alter this in order to exclude weekends?

Credits to Tom Sharpe.

Comment: Check NETWORKDAYS()

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the dates that represent the month (start of the month as follows) and put in on cell `C1`. It is an array formula, so no need to drag it to the right:

```
=EDATE(DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1), SEQUENCE(,12,0))
```

Now to calculate the working dates you can use `NETWORKDAYS` function as @P.b pointed out in the comment, checking first for the condition when two date intervals overlap:

```
=IF(AND(C1<=$B2,EOMONTH(C1,0)>=$A2), 
 NETWORKDAYS(MAX(C1,$A2), MIN(EOMONTH(C1,0),$B2)),0)
```

Put the formula in `C2` and drag the formula to the right. Here is the output:
[image]

This is the condition to check for two intervals `A`,`B` overlap:

```
AND(startA <= endB, endA >= startB)
```

In `C2` you can use an array solution too, via `MAP` function for example. We use `LET` function for easy reading and composition:

```
=LET(SOM,C1:N1, EOM,EOMONTH(1*SOM,0), startP,A2, endP,B2, 
 olaps,(SOM <= endP) * (EOM >= startP),
 MAP(olaps,SOM,EOM,LAMBDA(o,s,e,IF(o=0,0,
  NETWORKDAYS(MAX(startP,s),MIN(endP,e))))))
```

so, there is no need to extend the formula to the right. `EOMONTH` gives an error when using a range, so we use the following trick `1*SOM` to convert it to an array to make it works.